# Is designing a PCB for the A4989 driver as simple as the application diagram seems to suggest?

Tags: datasheet, stepper-motor, driver

### [Datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/%7E/media/Files/Datasheets/A4989-Datasheet.ashx)

[image]

It looks like it just needs an MCU for logic supply, step and direction plus another higher voltage supply; that, along with eight external FETs. Is there a more detailed guide somewhere on how to design a circuit for the A4989?

I happened to find [this PCB](https://dirtypcbs.com/store/designer/details/4972/118/stepper-motor-driver-with-a4989) that goes with the A4989. There is a lot more on there than eight drivers, two signals and two supplies. Also, the typical application diagram in the A4989's datasheet didn't have any capacitors (which concerns me).

Ideally, I would prefer to just find a nearly all-in-one chip module like how [DVR8825 dev board](https://www.pololu.com/category/120/stepper-motor-drivers)'s size. But it seems anything around 4 A max has a large form factor (e.g., DVR6575). That is why I'm looking into designing something that uses the A4989.

---

Related question

[Designing stepper motor driver with A4989 chip to control NEMA 17 / NEMA 23 motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331773/designing-stepper-motor-driver-with-a4989-chip-to-control-nema-17-nema-23-moto)

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't that simple - that is just a block diagram.

For more details, see the A4989 Demo Board schematic and PCB layout.